# How to select data from `MS Access with Unicode in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to Insert and Select data As Unicode to MS Access With VBA Code . It doesn't work Please Help me

```
Select * from Table Where Unicode_Name like '% Unicode_Character%'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

use `N` for `nvarchar`

```
Select * from Table Where Unicode_Name like N'% Unicode_Character%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Access uses Unicode by default.

But the wildcard in Access is *, so this may do:

```
Select * from Table Where Unicode_Name Like '*Unicode_Character*'
```

If that fails, use *StrConv* to convert to/from Unicode.